# Updating a column in Django Rest Api causes 'Column cannot be null' error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to 'delete' a column by changing the status (Yes, it is in my model and is set upon creation) instead of physically deleting it from the database. I therefore created my view and queried the item. When I send a post request I keep getting an error 'Column 'seller_id' cannot be null'. I've been researching and I see that in models.py I should just change `null=True`. The problem is I don't want that column to be able to be null when creating an item. Is there a way I can update a single field without having to update the non-nullable field? Do I need to include the non-nullable info when updating?

models.py

```
seller = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, blank=True, null=False, on_delete=models.SET('inactive'), related_name='product', verbose_name='User')
```

views.py

```
class ProductDeleteView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductDeleteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('pk', None) is not None:
            return Product.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        else:
            data = {'full_messages': ['Could not delete product.']}
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    def delete(self):
        product = queryset
        product.status = 99
        product.save()

        data = {'full_messages': ['Product deleted successfully.']}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserDeleteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['status']
```

Comment: You don't need to send post request. Send ***HTTP PATCH*** request instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`ListCreateAPIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) class doesn't provide any ***delete action*** by default. For deletion operations, use [**`generics.DestroyAPIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#destroyapiview) class and [override **`perform_destroy(...)`** and **`destroy(...)`** methods](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/?q=perform_destroy#methods) to get desired result

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics


class ProductDeleteView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    # serializer_class = ProductDeleteSerializer # you don't need a serializer for deletion
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        instance.status = 99
        instance.save()

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({'detail': 'deleted'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

To delete (temporary) the **`Product`** instance, you need to call **`/path/to/end-point/<product_id>/`** using ***HTTP DELETE***